# How to make css grid elements scale to the same height when scaling page width?

Tags: html, css

I want my #sec-1 article and .sec-1-img to scale to the same height when adjusting the site width, but I can't figure out how?

```css
body
{
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.container
{
    max-width: 1130px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.site-header
{
    background-color: #1f025c;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;

}

.logo
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo .img-logo
{
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.fixedMenu
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    top: 20px;
}

.burger
{
    z-index: 1;
}

.site-header input
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 0;
}

.site-header input:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.site-header input:checked ~ nav
{
    display: block;
}

.site-header nav
{
    display: none;
}

.site-header nav ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.site-header nav a 
{
    background-color: #1f025c;
    color: #bfbbc7;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.site-header nav a:hover
{
    color:  #0056b3;

}

.sec-1-img img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#sec-1 article
{
    padding: 50px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #a454fd, #2b05df);
    color: white;

}

#sec-1 article h1
{
    font-size: 34px;
}

#sec-1 article a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    
}



/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {



}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    .site-header
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .site-header nav
    {
        display: block;
    }

    .site-header nav li 
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .fixedMenu
    {
        display: none;
    }

    #sec-1
    {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    }

}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Elements</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.2/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/webfontkit-roboto/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="site-header">
            <div class="logo">
                <div class="img-logo">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="site logo">
                </div>
                
                <h1>ELEMENTS</h1>                
            </div>

            <input type="checkbox" class="fixedMenu">
            <img src="img/menu.png" alt="burger menu" class="fixedMenu burger">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#sec-1"> HOME </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> ABOUT </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> SERVICES </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> PORTFOLIO </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <section id="sec-1">
            <article>
                <header>
                  <h1>DISCOVER SOMETHING BRAND NEW</h1>  
                </header>
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus veniam, atque totam rerum repellat velit quae omnis consequatur debitis harum laudantium at laborum iure! Veritatis accusantium assumenda mollitia quas consequuntur!</p>
                <a href="#"> CONTACT US </a>
            </article>
            <div class="sec-1-img">
                <img src="https://placehold.jp/375x271.png" alt="working girl">
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="sec-2">
            <article>
                <header>
                    <h1>
                        <span>ABOUT</span> WEB ELEMENTS
                    </h1>
                </header>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit blanditiis laudantium tempora eius saepe totam. Dicta quam nesciunt velit nisi praesentium alias ratione nam blanditiis minus! Facere sequi voluptates possimus?</p>
                <img src="https://placehold.jp/375x271.png" alt="sketch">
            </article>
        </section>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```